# how to combine html nodeList from multiple get elements

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, google-apps-script, web-applications

I want to combine `html elements` and get values out of it using `array method` is there anyway to do it, I think I don't know how to combine it as `nodeList`

So I use get elements then `array.unshift` to add elements into one variable

```js
var elemsLabel = document.querySelectorAll('[id$="LabelSet"]')
// TO achieve something like
// elemsLabel.unshift(document.getElementById('SubHeader'))
// elemsLabel.unshift(document.getElementById('Header'))

// This what I have tried so far
elemsLabel += Array.from(elemsLabel).unshift(document.getElementById('SubHeader'))
elemsLabel += Array.from(elemsLabel).unshift(document.getElementById('Header'))
// I think I stuck only this above part, so below after 'var values'_
// is the reason I need to combine them into one variable

console.log(elemsLabel)

var values = []
for (var z = 0; z < elemsLabel.length; z++) {
  values[z] = elemsLabel[z].value
}

console.log(values)
```

```html
<input type="text" id="Header" value="head">
<input type="text" id="SubHeader" value="SubHeader">

<input type="text" id="docMyNameLabelSet" value="Name">
<input type="text" id="docMyIdLabelSet" value="Id">
<input type="text" id="docMyAddressLabelSet" value="Address">
```

so the result should be like `['head','SubHeader','Name','Id','Address']`

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is converting `elemsLabel` to string using `+=`operator. Use spread operator(`...`) on the node list to convert it to array. Also `.unshift()` doesn't return the unshifted array, but the number of elements added.

```js
var elemsLabel = [...document.querySelectorAll('[id$="LabelSet"]')]
elemsLabel.unshift(document.getElementById('SubHeader'))
elemsLabel.unshift(document.getElementById('Header'))
console.log(elemsLabel)

/*var values = []
for (let z = 0; z < elemsLabel.length; z++) {
  values[z] = elemsLabel[z].value
}

console.log(values)*/
console.log(elemsLabel.map(e => e.value))
```

```html
<input type="text" id="Header" value="head">
<input type="text" id="SubHeader" value="SubHeader">

<input type="text" id="docMyNameLabelSet" value="Name">
<input type="text" id="docMyIdLabelSet" value="Id">
<input type="text" id="docMyAddressLabelSet" value="Address">
```

Comment: This is Amazing I learn `[... ]` new thing to me. Thanks a lot

Comment: @zummontt `var elemsLabel = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[id$="LabelSet"]'))` should work the same. You just messed up the syntax.

Comment: Oh! that's why. I'm getting used to it